# ¿Cómo puedo controlar el tiempo de sesión del usuario?

Tags: django

Me gustaría saber como hacer para que a los 5 minutos el usuario "x" si está inactivo se desconecte su sesión en Django, si el usuario esta en la pagina moviendose por la web no me gustaria que se desconectase. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola amigo espero te encuentres bien, la manera mas sencilla es con django-session-timeout

Lo instalas con:

```
pip install django-session-timeout
```

Después para configurarlo en tus settings, en tu MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES agregas:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    # ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware',
    # ...
]
```

También en tu settings agregas en segundos cuanto tiempo quieres que dure la sesión con:

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_SECONDS = 3600  # 1 hora
```

Y por ultimo puedes redirigir a una url cuando se da el timeout, por ejemplo un template donde diga que tu sesión expiro, se hace de esta manera:

```
SESSION_TIMEOUT_REDIRECT = 'mi_url/'
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Agrego lo que comentaba el compañero en los comentarios de abajo, si quieres que se expire después de un tiempo de inactividad en la aplicación es necesario definir este setting:

SESSION_EXPIRE_AFTER_LAST_ACTIVITY = True

Comment: Pero eso te saca si o si aunque estes navegando por la web, yo quiero que si estas inactivo es decir sin mover el raton por decirlo asi que se salga de la sesión, pero si estas navegando que no te saque.

Comment: Para esto tienes otro flag, SESSION_EXPIRE_AFTER_LAST_ACTIVITY = True esta hara que se expire la sesion contando el tiempo despues de la ultima actividad que realizaste, en caso de no hacer nada en el sitio, entrar a otras secciones, etc va a empezar a contar. Puedes ver los demas settings aca: https://github.com/LabD/django-session-timeout

Comment: Muchas gracias! me sirvió!

Comment: De nada, si te sirvió la respuesta puedes marcarla como aceptada para futuras referencias de quienes tengan esta misma duda.